# Drag any shape in Canvas of HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop, drawing

I'm experimenting of using javascript to draw something in HTML5.
And I want the shape can be interactive.
I know that I can calc the current mouse's pos whether or not fall into the shape(any shape, maybe irregular shape.) by javascript.
But it's too trivial.
Is it there some api or lib to do this calc in some convinience.
Like, just for example.

```
var anyshape = new Shape();
anyshape.addEventListen('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

or

```
var anyshape = new Shape();
anyshape.onMouseMove = function(){};
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) provides shape dragging out of the box. There's also support for event listening and detection of objects clicked/hovered/etc.

```
var myShape = /* any shape */;
canvas.observe('mouse:down', function(e) {
  if (e.memo.target === myShape) {
    /* mouse down on myShape */
  }
});
```

Also take a look at [event inspector demo](http://fabricjs.com/events/).

Comment: But if we have a large amount of shape. We should write a bunch of if else or switch/case. It's a headache to maintain these code. I need a more clean way.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta implement all that functionality yourself or else use a library.

If you don't want to use a library, I've written a [few tutorials](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) on making movable shapes.

I'd highly recommend taking a look at SVG and seeing if that would suit your needs better. Complex paths that have event listeners and hit testing built in are already there in SVG.

Comment: Your tutorials is not exactly what I need.

Comment: It's not exactly, but the concept is the same. You have to keep track of everything about the shapes that you want to make and do the hit testing yourself or else use a library. There is no clean built-in way. What might be better for you is SVG, where a lot of this is built in.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-path-tutorial/ kinetic gives you the best and most easy way. You can now simply add multiple svgs and event listeners in a for loop.

```
for{
create shape code
add event listener
console log - kinetic rocks
```

}